# Minimizing pen lifts in a pen plotter or similar device

Tags: optimization, plot

I'm looking for references to algorithms for plotting on a mechanical pen plotter.

Specifically, I have a list of straight vectors, each representing a line to be plotted. First I want to remove duplicate vectors, so each line is only plotted once. That's easy enough.

Second, there are many vectors that intersect, sometimes at endpoints, but not always. They can be plotted in any order, but I want to find an order that reduces the number of times the pen must be lifted, preferably to a minimum though I understand that may take a long time to compute, if it's computable at all. Vectors that intersect can be broken into smaller vectors if that helps. But generally, if the pen is moving in a straight line, it's best to keep it moving that way as long as possible. So, two parallel vectors joined end to end could be combined into a single vector, etc.

This sounds like some variety of graph theory problem, but I don't know much about that. Can anyone point me to references or algorithms I need to study? Or maybe example code?

Thanks,

Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is an example of the [Chinese postman problem](https://service.projectplace.com/pp/pp.cgi/r461265613) which is an NP-complete problem. The most wellknown NP-complete problem is the [Travelling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). Common for all NP-complete problems are that they can all be translated into eachother. There are no known algorithms for solving any of them in a time that is polynomial dependent of the number of nodes in the input, they are non-polynomial (NP).

For your case I would suggest some simple heuristics. Don't overdo it, just pick anything quite simple like going in a straight line as long as possible and then lift the pen to the closest available starting point and go on from there.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's what I was afraid of. I have a few heuristics to try, so I guess I'll experiment a bit.